# CollapsingToolbarLayout wrong title display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following code, and I don't know why after collapse the toolbar the title is not showed properly. Check the text "T. My tanatory".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_tanatorio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/t_tanatory"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_tanatosalas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Any ideas why this effect?

Comment: have you try to remove that TitleMargin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set your toolbar in your activity onCreate

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.myToolbar))//Kotlin

setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.myToolbar) //java
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check using layout_scrollFlags in your toolbar and  adjust expandedTitleMarginEnd and start in collapsing toolbar layout, also remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from imageview

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="#039BE5"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="180dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="100dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover_pic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/meetup_details"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            </ImageView>



        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```